# Applying the cycle algorithm for Hamiltonian graphs

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

I have this graph and the idea is to produce a planar graph.

I first choose a Hamiltonian cycle c $$1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6$$

The edges not in the cycle c are $$(13),(14),(15),(24),(26),(46)$$
We will have two sets.

Set A contains edges that can be drawn without crossing inside c and set B which contains the edges that can be drawn without crossing outside c.

I pick an edge not in c for example $$(13$$ and I place it in set A. The edges incompatible to $(13)$ are $(24)$ and $(26)$ and thet go into set B.
I then do this for all the edges.
Is this process right?
I have in my notes that you test the compatibility of edges in set B and if they are not compatible then you stop because the graph is non planar.
The problem is that every time I do this with any question that I know is planar, I always get non compatible edges in B.